# Are languages such as Wu, Yue, Jin, Min, Hakka, Xiang, Gan, Huizhou, and Pinghua written in Classical Chinese or Written vernacular?

Tags: classical-chinese

[image]
Is language such as Wu, Yue, Jin, Min, Hakka, Xiang, Gan, Huizhou, and Pinghua written in Classical Chinese or Written vernacular?

Comment: You might want to think about the question again. A language written in Classical Chinese is, in fact, Classical Chinese. If Yue Chinese is written down, the language is Yue Chinese. Maybe you meant to ask whether any of those languages have standardised orthographies.

Comment: Not counting ethnic minorities, there are only two standard forms of written Chinese today - traditional and simplified. For each dialect, there could be words or phrases that fitting the local custom in speaking language using the standard Chinese letters.

Answer (score 1):

Not all languages have written form.

For many dialects in Mainland China, people there have to translate their dialects into Mandarin (Simplified Chinese) to write them down. But some ethnic minorities do have their own written languages, for example, Tibetan language.

Hong Kong people and Taiwanese, use Traditional Chinese. By the way, Hong Kong Traditional Chinese is different from Taiwan Traditional Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

《何典》is a novel which uses both Wu and Mandarin.

========== from zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/何典===========
維基百科，自由的百科全書

《何典》，又名《十一才子書·鬼話連篇錄》，是清代用吳語和官話撰寫的借鬼說事的諷刺小說，被稱為天下奇書之一。作者為上海人張南莊，題簽中名為「過路人」；由「纏夾二先生」（陳得仁）評。在五四新文化運動中，此書得到新文化運動名家的推崇。

劉半農極推崇《何典》的理由之一是「善用俚言土語」。[1]魯迅曾經為《何典》作序。
最早的上海話文字資料

何典是迄今我們所能見到的最早的上海話文字資料，《何典》全文用夾雜官話及上海話寫成，是一種上海話小說體，充斥上海方言口語的成語、俗諺、詞彙及慣用說法，提供考察200年前的上海話面貌實據。[2]